# how run a command on several files and save the outputs for each file in a different file

Tags: text-processing

I have a vcf-file (file.vcf) and several population files `(HA1.txt, HA1.txt, HA2.txt,...,HA28.txt)` containing individual IDs.

each population file looks like this (each line is one individual):

```
$ cat HA1.txt
    QQ48_SD1A-37    
    ED19_SD1A40-3_357
    TT335_SD1A-20
    HH356_SD1A-7
    Q029B_SD1A38    
    HT73_SD1A-28    
    HT288_SD1A-24
    Q004B_SD1A-1    
    Q027_SD1A-4
    Q096_SD1A-40
```

I want to extract the depth of coverage for each individual in each population.
how can I run this command: `grep -v "^#" file.vcf | cut -f 10 | cut -d ':' -f2` for each individual in population files and save the output of each population in a seperate file?

My desired output for each population looks like this:

```
.   6   4   6   .   5   .   10  .   7   .
.   9   16  8   3   8   .   16  9   22  .
.   8   11  8   .   8   .   16  8   18  .
6   20  12  20  12  28  3   24  4   26  14
6   25  15  24  13  32  3   25  3   25  15
```

each column in one individual!

Comment: yes, I agree and  tried to ask my question in a better way!

Comment: show us a samplified version of your `file.vcf`, please, here I cannot recognize how your expected output is generated with sample input  `HA1.txt` which is irrelevant to the output and the command you are using

Comment: Chrom1 1308 . A T 6622.86 . 0448 GT:DP:DPR:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL 0/0:8:8,0:8:292:0:0:0,-2.40824,-26.6303 0/0:6:6,0:6:247:0:0:0,-1.80618,-21.0485 0/1:18:18,6:12:438:6:211:-13.9004,0,-32.5893

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *; do grep '[pattern]' "$file" | cut -f 10 | cut -d ':' -f2 > "$file.output"; done
```